# Can we have a profile URL?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, profile-page

Like the Facebook profile URL, LinkedIn URL, can we have a URL at Stack Overflow? Maybe it can be a good addition to a resume!

Comment: +1, I don't see anything worth downvoting this question, he is clearly asking about url that can be used externally to link to SO account, the current URL has a number in it which looks like session id so you can't tell if it will work as a link to your account ... I consider it good question.

Comment: @stefanB:  On meta, downvotes can mean either the normal bad/no info/something question or it can just simply mean a person does not like the feature request. So don't worry, that is normal on meta to see feature requests with lots of downvotes.

Comment: I have included `stackoverflow.com/u/[id]` in my CV/resume as this is tidier than the full thing.

Comment: ***

Now...
------

Can you tell me where the URL change section is ??? (Please)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't get it. What is wrong with:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135920/faiz

Comment: What is the number in there. That looks ugly :(

Comment: probably it's confusing to users because the url contains some number which looks like session id, maybe you could try to explain the number and how to use the url ... for others looking for answers look further down the page for actual answer to this question ...

Comment: Looks a bit bulky on my resume...

Comment: Then don't put URLs on your resume. Problem solved.

Comment: I think he has a point, what he meant is a short nice URL, look for LinkedIn, you can shorten your profile URL, GitHub is already short and nice, Google Plus also and most of the website.

Comment: I can't believe this hasn't been resolved. I would like something to add to a business card for example. just get rid of /users/<number>/

Comment: @GEOCHET because my interviewer does not have time to enter that 6 digit number to view my stackoverflow profile whose ugly url I added on paper resume

Comment: @GEOCHET You seem like a big hater of this idea. I just want to make the point that the OP has a valid question which is still not resolved the way everyone is expecting. An ideal profile URL would have been stackoverflow.com/username. Of course I can add my own shortened URL but that won't have stackoverflow name within it. I don't think you will be ever convinced.

Comment: These comments perfectly depict everything wrong with Stack Overflow.

Comment: I see that `stackoverflow.com/u/[id]` works so I've included that on my CV/resume

Answer (score 25):

You already have a profile url:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/82961/faiz

If you don't like the "faiz" part (perhaps you want to show your real name for resume purposes), you can put anything you want after that last "/" character to share around.  The important part is the ID.  For example, this works just fine:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/82961/Joel-Coehoorn

Comment: Joel!? What happened to you?

Comment: Amid all the sarcasm and surprise it seems like this is the only helpful answer to the original question, I've been looking for similar thing and the top voted 'answer' does not really help to explain what are the components of url that you get for SO account

Comment: I'm a cookie: http://stackoverflow.com/users/292145/

Comment: It's been 12 years. Still curious what happened to Joel.

Comment: @wha7ever turned into faiz, perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can use the StackExchange short URL form. This will automatically redirect to the user profile.

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/u/<uid>
```

https://meta.stackexchange.com/u/135920

If you want something that looks good on the resume or business card, then you can always use your own domain (if you have one). For example, something like this:

[http://faiz.com/stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/u/135920)
[http://faiz.com/facebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22044)
[http://faiz.com/twitter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22044)

Answer (score 6):

Consider making yourself a customized [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) or [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com) to point to your Stack Overflow URL.

Comment: Not too professional looking though.

Answer (score 5):

**Clean url to SO account for external linking?**

The url is `http://stackoverflow.com/users/<uid>/<anything>`

The uid is fixed, and will never change for a given account.  Anything can be placed after the uid - SO ignores it.

Customized URLs beyond that are not currently possible because everything on SO is tied to the UID, not the username, and there may in fact be several "John F" in the system.  To implement something like this would require a system like the Careers website, where you have to reserve your URL.

While technically possible, there is no compelling reason (yet) why the current UID system won't meet everyone's needs.

Answer (score 1):

The question and comments appear to ask that:

**stackoverflow.com/*uid***

automatically redirect to:

**stackoverflow.com/user/*uid*/profile**

The technical cost of the request is trivial, but it brings up philosophy.  Some will resist violently: accommodating users wanting different values from Stack Overflow costs ego.

Expect no change this decade.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/u/id redirects.

Answer (score 1):

I've set up `stackoverflow.name` to generate a vanity link for Stack Overflow profiles. For example, for my account, the generated link is:

```
https://stackoverflow.name/sigpwned
```

You can visit https://stackoverflow.name/ to set up your own link!

Comment: How can we know you don't collect data while redirecting? Sites like tinyurl has privacy policy and everything. Not saying you collect any data, but some people might not like the lack of confirmation that you don't.

Comment: I'm actually somewhat unsure what problem this solves. A short link? That one is possible with URL shortener. A personalized link? That one is also not so difficult, you could as well just purchase a domain, they're super cheap unless you want something really stellar, but for most purposes it's still 5-15$ per year

Comment: This comes with its own privacy concerns but I appreciate the effort.